# Custom Adminhtml Grid - Set Global Width

Tags: adminhtml, grid, grid-serlization

I've created my own adminhtml grid for a module and was wondering if somebody could point out how I can adjust the width of the whole grid itself? (I.E to only utilize 80% of the page width).

Please note that I am **not asking how to change the column width,** but the % of the page that the grid's width will occupy.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I've got a feeling it will be in the Grid.php file?

> class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Custom_Grid extends 
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

`public function __construct(){`
`parent::__construct();` 
`#Somewhere here?`
`}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that from css.
Add to your grid page a custom css file with this line:

```
#ID_OF_GRID {width:80%}
```

Use firebug, or view source to see the value for `ID_OF_GRID`.
Usually the id is the value you set in the grid constructor using:

```
$this->setId('...');
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent solution. Could you please indicate to me what your preferred way of adding custom css? I went the route of <action method="addCSS"> in the layout.xml file of mine.